# How to display a widget on a page with no theme?

Tags: plugins, themes, widgets

I would like only a widget to appear on a page, is this possible? As in if I created a page, I am wondering if I can make a page just display the widgets contents with no headers, sidebars, just blank. Essentially if there was no widget added it would be a blank page. Is this possible?

Comment: `get_option('sidebars_widgets')` maybe - haven't tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes).  It's completely possible, but you have to go through the right process.  First you should register a new "sidebar" and call it whatever you want to call that page you want the widget to display on.  Then you need to call that sidebar into the page's template file, after which you can add and remove widgets from your dashboard.

This all hinges on you having access to the code, if you don't I am afraid the answer is probably not.

If you can alter the code, then all you have to do what I said above, and create a new page using the [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) you created.

Comment: Okay, so to get this right, I just need to create a new page template? I am able to use shortcode for this plugin as well, so I don't need to use the widget if it is easier.

Comment: You could definitely use shortcode if you want to.  However if you want it to be a completely blank page, you will need to create a new page template.